# Animation in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, css-animations, sapui5

I have two matrix layout. The first one contains seven images placed like a grid. How can we arrange all the images vertically in the second layout with animation?

-Thanks

Comment: What kind of animation is in your mind?

Comment: @TimGerlach I want to move the contents of cells from one matrix layout to another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to 1) detect the location of your target matrixlayoutrowcells, 2) to detach the content of the source cell and 3) attach it to the target cell, than it's nothing more than just incorporating some CSS animations ;-)

See this example of a moving sap.ui.commons.Image : http://jsbin.com/jafuk/1/edit