# Setting coordinates of an object inside a page in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I want to add an image in the page inside a view in sapui5 at a specific location using jquery.offset() method. However, it is not working. The debugger shows the default offset value of the image. Please help.

I have an image with id, "id_image", and I used the following code for setting the offset of the image :

```
var Image = new sap.m.Image("id_image",{
            src:"images/myImage.png"
        });
$("#id_image").offset({top:"200px", left:"300px"});
return new sap.m.Page("id_page",{
            title: "View",
            content: [Image

            ]
        });
```

Comment: Share the HTML Code or Share jsfiddle URL!

Comment: @Venkat Its not an html page.I am using sapui5. I have a view. Inside the view i am returning a page that contains this image.

Comment: Share the Returning HTML Code

Comment: This will never work this way. You are setting the offset to an image which isn't even added to the DOM model yet. You may try in onAfterRendering event of the view, but even then I doubt this will work...

Comment: @Qualiture It is also not working in onAfterRendering. Do you have any idea how can i set the images at fixed coordinates when the page gets loaded.

Comment: Can you post a jsbin/jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, there are a few issues with your code:

1. You are setting the offset of an element which isn't loaded in the DOM yet, so setting an offset at this stage would not have any effect. Best solution is to set it in the `onAfterRendering` event of the view.
2. [According to the jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset-coordinates), the coordinates of the `offset()` method only accepts numbers (10, 20, etc) whereas you have provided a CSS unit ('100px' etc)

See this working jsbin example http://jsbin.com/jafuk/1/edit where the offset is set in the `onAfterRendering` event.

And since you have asked about animation [in another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371362/animation-in-sapui5), I have added that as a bonus. I'll leave it as an exercise on how to detach a control/image from one MatrixLayout(Cell) to another :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, HTML transformations using JQuery is a not good idea. 
For your purposes you should use *sap.ui.commons.layout.AbsoluteLayout* to define image offset.

```
var oImage = new sap.m.Image("id_image",{
        src:"images/myImage.png"
    });
var oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.AbsoluteLayout({
        width: "" //Adjust width
        height: "" //and height for container
    }).addContent(oImage, {top:"200px",left:"300px"});
return new sap.m.Page("id_page",{
        title: "View",
        content: [oLayout

        ]
    });
```